# Is KeyUpdate feature required for TLS 1.3 protocol?

Tags: ssl, protocols, rfc, tls1.3

In TLS 1.3 (RFC8446), there is a new HS message 'KeyUpdate', which allows either peer to request a key update.  We are trying to find out if ‘KeyUpdate’ is a required feature for TLS 1.3.  By reading RFC8446, KeyUpdate doesn’t seem to be an option you can turn off at the negotiation phase.

I’ve been testing our command line TLS client against https://tls13.1d.pw (TLS1.3-only web server), but it fails to fetch a page when ‘KeyUpdate’ record is sent by the server because 'KeyUpdate' is not supported by the TLS implementation that we use.

Would anybody know if the feature is required?

Also, what’s the best way to test a command line TLS client against a real-life server using TLS 1.3 protocol?  I can connect our client to a server like google.com, but I don't know how I can cause a traffic large enough to know whether KeyUpdate is used commonly in the real life.

Any input is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question because we use TLS between our client and server and my question is if we should implement key update and after which time or data amount we should do it. We use OpenSSL on both sides, so the server side is also under our control.

What I found out is that some TLS implementations implement automatic key updates (GnuTLS and NSS are mentioned on a slide deck from Red Hat: [tls13.pdf](https://archive.fosdem.org/2019/schedule/event/tls13_apis/attachments/slides/3387/export/events/attachments/tls13_apis/slides/3387/tls13.pdf)).

So the answer is probably yes. The other side may request a key update and if you connect to such a server, it may trigger this manually or it may be triggered automatically depending on the SSL library that is used.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Yes, it does sound like KeyUpdate is a mandatory feature for the TLS 1.3 protocol.  I was also asking around offline and came to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Key Update is required, when [AEAD-LIMITS] is reached. When using AEAD (AES-GCM) upto 24 million records can be encrypted, before reaching the limit.
Please find the snapshot from RFC, where this is explained in details

"*5.5. Limits on Key Usage
There are cryptographic limits on the amount of plaintext which can
be safely encrypted under a given set of keys. [AEAD-LIMITS]
provides an analysis of these limits under the assumption that the
underlying primitive (AES or ChaCha20) has no weaknesses.
Implementations SHOULD do a key update as described in Section 4.6.3
prior to reaching these limits.
For AES-GCM, up to 2^24.5 full-size records (about 24 million) may be
encrypted on a given connection while keeping a safety margin of
approximately 2^-57 for Authenticated Encryption (AE) security. For
ChaCha20/Poly1305, the record sequence number would wrap before the
safety limit is reached.*"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).